# Redirect from plugin in ajax request in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a application in ZF2 framework, in this I am sending and requesting data to/from a web services using http_client request. In my application I have a multi step form which is changing form steps using ajax.
Now if I submit a form using ajax request, it hit my controller and then from controller I call a common function of controller plugin for all type of request in this case if there is any error in web service then I want to redirect to login page but it not redirecting parent layout/page instead of this it show the login page in ajax loaded form part(where my form is changing through ajax).

Please help me to redirect main page to login page instead of show login page in ajax loaded part.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a javascript expert but you need to do the redirect in the javascript and not your controller.

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

You can pass the redirect url from your controller if you need to redirect to different locations depending on your logic.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage).

Hope this points you in the right direction.